# Question about uniform convergence with real variable

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

From Raghavan Narasimhan, Yves Nievergelt - Complex Analysis in One Variable:

> Let $0 < \delta < 1$, and set  $u(z) = u_\delta (z) =
> > |z|^{-2}(\log(\delta \phi(z)))^{-2}, z \neq 0$,
>
> then $u_\delta (z) \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$ uniformly on $|z| \geq \rho$ for any $\rho > 0$

What mean that $u_\delta(z) \to 0$ uniformly on $|z| \geq \rho$ ? I know that uniform convergence implies a sequence $({f_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of functions. But here we have $(u_\delta)_{\delta \in (0,1)}$.

$\textbf{Edit}$:
Clarifications about $\phi$ function.

$\phi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{C})$ with folowing properties:

$\phi(z) = |z|^2$ for $|z| \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$\phi(z) = \frac{1}{2}$ for $|z| \geq \frac{3}{4}$

$0 < \phi(z) < 1$ for $z \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am making a very reasonable guess at the author's intent. I can't know for certain what they meant without more context. For example, what is $\phi$? At the moment I have no way of checking whether my interpretation of the statement is true.

It's easy to generalise the definition for sequences of functions to this case. Just this:

> For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta'>0$ such that for *all* $0<\delta<\delta'$ and all $z$, $|z|\ge\rho$, we have $|u_\delta(z)|<\epsilon$.

Note that this is stronger than saying: for each sequence $(\delta_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset(0,1)$ converging to zero, $(u_{\delta_n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to zero.

We can generalise this further for maps $\Lambda\to Y^X$ where $Y$ is a uniform space and $\Lambda$ is a topological space. Maybe we can generalise it even further than that.

Comment: So this definition will be equivalent to $\lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} (\sup\limits_{x \in A} |f_\delta (x) - f(x)|) = 0$ ?

Comment: @MathLearner Yes, if you take $\lim_{\delta\to0\color{red}{^+}}$.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks you for help me! :) and for context I will edit the post to clarify the $\phi$ function

Comment: I made the edit

Comment: @MathLearner The statement is correct in my interpretation. In fact, the smoothness assumption on $\phi$ is irrelevant, I don't even care if $\phi$ is continuous

Comment: thanks! Aaaaa... now I don't know how to show that $\lim\limits_{\delta \to 0} (\sup\limits_{x \in A} |f_\delta (x) - f(x)|) = 0$... Can you help me with an edit in your answer please?

Comment: @MathLearner Hint: it suffices to show $|z|^2\log^2(\delta\phi(z))$ uniformly tends to infinity in some sense. $\log^2(\delta\phi)\ge\log^2(\delta)$.